# Extjs6 dynamically modify font size

Tags: extjs6-classic

How to modify the font size of the page in Extjs6, for example, I make a scroll wheel on the page which is small, medium, and large, and then provide the user to choose. After the selection, the overall font of the page is displayed according to the user's choice of size. My Ext version is 6.2 people who want to know Give an implementation suggestion or plan. thank you very much

Comment: Although not dynamically, changing the following theme variable will change the font size. Maybe it's a start.
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Global_CSS.html#css_var-S-$font-size

Comment: Thank you. I have modified the font here, but what I want to do is to provide users with the option of font size on the page, and then the font size is displayed on the page as a whole for automatic modification